# CS50: Wordle: Todo#7 reusing returned variable outside of function

Tags: c, cs50

TODO #7. Printing the game results. I want to reuse the variable score but it states it's undeclared and not sure how to not have to enter this part in the main function.

when I run the below code I get the following error: use of undeclared identifier 'guess'

if (guess == choice)

The link to the problem set for further information: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/2/wordle50/

I am struggling to use variable score outside of its function. choice (the word selected by the program, based on word size selected by user, to be guessed by user) and guess (the user's guess at the word which is choice). I must have watched the functions short video and lecture segment like 15 times over the last couple of weeks throughout multiple problem sets but still don't fully grasp it

How do I re-use guess and choice outside of its function? This is why I end up just putting everything inside main function.

Would appreciate if someone can point me to learning resource for this.

I have tried the following code and have tried re-initializing all the variables but doesn't seem feasible and am probably not understanding the concept.

I tried minimizing the amount of code copied here but that hasn't given the community here the required information but am not able to create a minimal reproducible example, maybe I will will be able to do that with more practice, but here is the full code, please don't be mad.

The issue here comes in the 8 lines after the following quoted lines:

QUOTE

```
// Print the game's result

// TODO #7
```

Unquote

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// each of our text files contains 1000 words
#define LISTSIZE 1000

// values for colors and score (EXACT == right letter, right place; CLOSE == right letter, wrong place; WRONG == wrong letter)
#define EXACT 2
#define CLOSE 1
#define WRONG 0

// ANSI color codes for boxed in letters
#define GREEN   "\e[38;2;255;255;255;1m\e[48;2;106;170;100;1m"
#define YELLOW  "\e[38;2;255;255;255;1m\e[48;2;201;180;88;1m"
#define RED     "\e[38;2;255;255;255;1m\e[48;2;220;20;60;1m"
#define RESET   "\e[0;39m"

// user-defined function prototypes
string get_guess(int wordsize);
int check_word(string guess, int wordsize, int status[], string choice);
void print_word(string guess, int wordsize, int status[]);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    // TODO #1
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./wordle wordsize\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int wordsize = 0;
    wordsize = atoi(argv[1]);

    // ensure argv[1] is either 5, 6, 7, or 8 and store that value in wordsize instead
    // TODO #2
    if (wordsize < 4 || wordsize > 9)
    {
        printf("Error: wordsize must be either 5, 6, 7, or 8\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // open correct file, each file has exactly LISTSIZE words
    char wl_filename[6];
    sprintf(wl_filename, "%i.txt", wordsize);
    FILE *wordlist = fopen(wl_filename, "r");
    if (wordlist == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file %s.\n", wl_filename);
        return 1;
    }

    // load word file into an array of size LISTSIZE
    char options[LISTSIZE][wordsize + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < LISTSIZE; i++)
    {
        fscanf(wordlist, "%s", options[i]);
    }

    // pseudorandomly select a word for this game
    srand(time(NULL));
    string choice = options[rand() % LISTSIZE];

    // allow one more guess than the length of the word
    int guesses = wordsize + 1;
    bool won = false;

    // print greeting, using ANSI color codes to demonstrate
    printf(GREEN"This is WORDLE50"RESET"\n");
    printf("You have %i tries to guess the %i-letter word I'm thinking of\n", guesses, wordsize);

    // main game loop, one iteration for each guess
    for (int i = 0; i < guesses; i++)
    {
        // obtain user's guess
        string guess = get_guess(wordsize);

        // array to hold guess status, initially set to zero
        int status[wordsize];

        // set all elements of status array initially to 0, aka WRONG
        // TODO #4
        for(int status_index = 0 ; status_index < wordsize ; status_index++)
        {
            status[status_index] = 0;
        }

        // Calculate score for the guess
        int score = check_word(guess, wordsize, status, choice);

        printf("Guess %i: ", i + 1);

        // Print the guess
        print_word(guess, wordsize, status);

        // if they guessed it exactly right, set terminate loop
        if (score == EXACT * wordsize)
        {
            won = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    // Print the game's result
    // TODO #7

    if (guess == choice)
    {
        printf("You won!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("choice: %s\n", choice);
    }

    // that's all folks!
    return 0;
}

string get_guess(int wordsize)
{
    string guess;
    int guess_int;
    // ensure users actually provide a guess that is the correct length
    // TODO #3
    do
    {
        guess = get_string("Input a %i-letter word: ", wordsize);
    }
    while ((guess_int = strlen(guess)) != wordsize);
    return guess;
}

int check_word(string guess, int wordsize, int status[], string choice)
{
    int score = 0;

    // compare guess to choice and score points as appropriate, storing points in status
    // TODO #5

    // HINTS
    // iterate over each letter of the guess
        for (int guess_index = 0 ; guess_index < wordsize ; guess_index++)
        {

        // iterate over each letter of the choice
            for (int choice_index = 0 ; choice_index < wordsize ; choice_index++)
            {

            // compare the current guess letter to the current choice letter
                // if they're the same position in the word, score EXACT points (green) and break so you don't compare that letter further
                if (guess[guess_index] == choice[guess_index])
                {
                    status[guess_index] = EXACT;
                    score = score + status[guess_index];
                    break;
                }
                // if it's in the word, but not the right spot, score CLOSE point (yellow)
                else if (guess[guess_index] == choice[choice_index])
                {
                    status[guess_index] = CLOSE;
                    score = score + status[guess_index];
                }
            }
        }
        // keep track of the total score by adding each individual letter's score from above

    return score;
}

void print_word(string guess, int wordsize, int status[])
{
    // print word character-for-character with correct color coding, then reset terminal font to normal
    // TODO #6
    for (int i = 0 ; i < wordsize ; i++)
    {
        if (status[i] == 2)
        {
            printf(GREEN"%c"RESET, guess[i]);
        }
        else if (status[i] == 1)
        {
            printf(YELLOW"%c"RESET, guess[i]);
        }
        else if (status[i] == 0)
        {
            printf(RED"%c"RESET, guess [i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please post a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as it is hard to understand what problem you are facing from just this short snippet of code.

Comment: Concerning "CS50: Wordle: Todo#7". Please heed the mandatory BP42, IHNIWYM.

Comment: What does `check_word` actually _do_? Perhaps you want to write a function with a more meaningful name, such as `calculate_word_score`, which actually _returns_ a value representing its score. So then, you could do `int score = calculate_word_score(word);`.

Comment: Thanks for editing the shown code. But it seems that you have misunderstood the concept of a [mre].

Comment: Some general hint: While many people might know that there is some CS50 course, you should not assume anyone knowing what the assignments look like. Something linke "CS50 wordle" or even "Todo#7" has absolutely no meaning to close to everyone here. Therefore you should provide all relevant details in the question.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using strings, given your `printf` statements, remember, you cannot directly compare strings in C, you need to use `strcmp()` from `string.h`

Comment: `string guess` is declared inside a for loop and does not exist outside of it. You need to move the declaration out of the loop. Also you cannot compare strings with `==` as the other comment says.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was convinced that I shouldn't change anything except under the TODO#7 set up the assessors but it seems there is not other way that moving the declaration of guess outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem with you.

Since I cannot use 'score' or 'guess' in todo7 because they all local variable, instead I started looking for a global variable. Then I found bool 'won' which is declared in main and gets the final result at last loop in main.

so here is my final code for todo7:

// TODO #7

```
if (won)
{
    printf("You won!\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Sorry, the word is: %s\n", choice);
}
// that's all folks!
```